# Compare two lists, one with a wildcard, and return a new list containing its difference

Tags: python-3.x

I am having difficulty figuring out how to produce this expectation given two lists, one used as a base to check against, and the other is a result list from a separate calculation.

## First list:

```
check = ['?', 'Z']
```

## Second list:

```
result = ['AZ', 'ZA', 'ZY', 'OZ']
```

What I have tried gets no where close but what it should do is check to see if each element in `check` is in `result` and if not, the element that fails to match in `result` should be swapped with the appropriate element in `check`.

## Expectation

```
expectation = ['?Z', 'Z?', 'Z?', '?Z']
```

The example here is minimal but the problem expands to situations with more than 2 characters.

Comment: Are there always going to be exactly two elements in `check`?

Comment: From the top of my mind I would use regex to replace the items in the second list which are not 'Z' or not in the first list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there would be a more elegant solution but this should work:

```py
check = ['?', 'Z']
result = ['AZ', 'ZA', 'ZY', 'OZ']
expectation = []  # ['?Z', 'Z?', 'Z?', '?Z']

for element in result:
    not_in_result = [char for char in check if char not in element]
    not_in_check = [char for char in element if char not in check]
    for char_not_in_result in not_in_result:
        for char_not_in_check in not_in_check:
            element = element.replace(char_not_in_check, char_not_in_result)
    expectation.append(element)

print(expectation)
# ['?Z', 'Z?', 'Z?', '?Z']
```

Comment: thank you very much; this is super helpful and is great to learn from